# Invalid Character inserting row in Oracle C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, devart

I have a small test to insert some values in a table (Oracle) from C# the thing is that I have a sql sentence (all types are numbers except for the date):

`insert into historicos values (2,1,1,to_date('01/08/2013','dd/mm/yyyy'), 0,1,25,25,36);`

I've tried many forms to insert (switching commas, changing functions, etc...)

I can insert with that sql command if I paste it in the SQLDeveloper, but when I try to execute that command from C# i get an `ORA-00911 Invalid character`

Do you know where's the problem?  Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not forgot removing " ; " at end of the query...